# Some Urdu characters not rendering correctly on UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, urdu

I faced an issue with rendering Urdu on UITextView. I have used NSAttributedString to render text, but some characters are not appearing well using **Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq** styled **Regular** and **AlviLahoriNastaleeq**font. You can see in first picture how a character on the second line is not correctly rendered

[image]

Here is another reference screenshot, please see lines 5 and 13 where some characters are not rendered correctly.

[image]

**What I have Tried**

**1-**
There are some characters that do not appear well i.e. **["بڑ", "ئز", "یز", "ڈ", "ز"]** I
tried to find all the occurrences of these characters using this tutorial [Find and Return the Ranges of All the Occurrences of a Given String in Swift][3]
Then change the font of all these occurrences to **Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq-Kasheeda** because this little change will not impact overall looking, but finding all occurrences of a single character in a string does not work well in urdu, but only the case when we find the first occurrence this will work well using `string.range(of: "ئز")`.

I have tested finding all occurrences of a substring in English that work well using the above tutorial method.
.
[3]: https://betterprogramming.pub/find-and-return-the-ranges-of-all-the-occurrences-of-a-given-string-in-swift-2a2015907a0e

**2-** Text is rendered well with **Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq-Kasheeda**, but I have to use  **Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq** styled **Regular**

Is there any workaround that displays all characters well for Urdu in **Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq** styled **Regular**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally get solved, use UILabel instead of UITextView**

Actually, UILabel renders Jameel Noori Nastaleeq without any issue but in the same context, UITextView causes issues.

According to my experience, **issue is with UITextView compatibility with Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq and AlviLahoriNastaleeq** also **Apple** should see into this issue.